# System Error Created prevention in salesforce

Tags: validation, system

I'm getting a custom validation system errors. How to prevent them:

**Error Email:**

Origin: LeadEmailHandler (this is an apex class)

Error: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Found a duplicate record for patrickg123@gmail.com:
 Patrick (Lead): http://na22.salesforce.com/: []

Link: https://na23.salesforce.com/

**System Error:**

[image]

what would be the reason for this emails?How to stop these system error coming to mail?

Answer (score 0):

This link seems applicable: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008ypdIAA.

Did you modify the ConsumerLeadEmailHandler class? It seems to be the culprit of your issue.

If you're the developer and are receiving the e-mails, I might suggest a rule to direct the e-mails to a specific directory in your inbox if you are looking to ignore them. Though, they are letting you know something bad is happening, so you might not want to blanket ignore them.